# How can I write a custom shortcode that takes a single string as an argument?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode that takes a single string as an argument, and then returns a hyperlink based on the string.  In the code below, the value of `$content` passed to my function is always `null` and I can't figure out why.  Where am I going wrong?

```php
function add_objective_hyperlink($atts, $content = null) {
    // var_dump($content);
    $the_objective = strtolower($content);
    $the_objective = str_replace(' ','-', $the_objective);
    $the_objective = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', $the_objective);
    $the_hyperlink = '<a href="https://example.com/objective/' . $the_objective . '">' . $content . '</a>';
    return $the_hyperlink;      
}

add_shortcode('obj', 'add_objective_hyperlink');
```

I'm passing my shortcode in like this within my post content: `[obj "The Thing I Want to Do"]`, and I'm expecting to see a hyperlink appear in my post.  My `var_dump($content)` always returns `string(0) ""`, though, which of course means there's no hyperlink in my page.

Comment: Relevant: [Add WordPress shortcode which sends parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39724530/2943403) and [Shortcode wordpress with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44090562/2943403) and [Pass argument to short code function in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67897765/2943403) and [Shortcode parameter not working in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75174483/2943403) and [How to pass parameter that ends up being part of a class name with wordpress shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31579430/2943403)

Comment: and [How to handle parameters in shortcode function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26536204/2943403) and [How to send page title as parameter in shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55313015/2943403) and [How to add category option to shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47645631/2943403) and [Wordpress, is it possible to add custom parameters to shortcode any widget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22225124/2943403) and [Wordpress : ShortCode and variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23376775/2943403)

Comment: slugify: `return sprintf('<a href="https://example.com/objective/%s">%s</a>', preg_replace('/[^a-z\d\- ]+/', '-', strtolower($obj)), $obj);`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my own code working by changing the inputs to my function from `($atts, $content)` to simply `($input)` (which is an array), then grabbing the first element of the array, converting it to a string, and then the rest of my code works as intended.

```php
function add_objective_hyperlink($input) {
    $the_content = (string)$input[0];
    $the_objective = $the_content;
    $the_objective = strtolower($the_objective);
    $the_objective = str_replace(' ','-', $the_objective);
    $the_objective = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', $the_objective);
    $the_hyperlink = '<a href="https://patrickmichaelregan.com/objective/' . $the_objective . '">' . $the_content . '</a>';
    return $the_hyperlink;      
}
add_shortcode('obj', 'add_objective_hyperlink');
```

This allows me to use `[obj "The Thing I Want To Do"]` as my shortcode.

Comment: But I still don't understand why the `$content` bit in my original code did not work as intended.  I'm missing something in the WP functions docs.

Comment: `$content` is a string representation of the enclosed content between `[shortcode]` and `[/shortcode]` (if used in this form). It doesn't ever include any information about attributes passed as part of the shortcode. See [docs for `add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/)

Comment: @esqew I feel like you understand this content well.  Please find a suitable dupe target to close with.